# Golang RethinkDB ChangeFeed Structure

Tags: go, struct, unmarshalling, rethinkdb

I was wondering if someone could explain how to unmarshal my changefeed cursor value to a specific struct type.

```
var message map[string]interface{}

for chatFeedCursor.Next(&message) {
    fmt.Println(message)
}
```

> map[new_val:map[club_id:ea2eb6e2-755f-4dad-922d-e3693b6e55c6
>   date:2017-04-07 14:48:17.714 +0100 +01:00
>   id:e389ab54-963e-4b33-9b34-adcb6ec5b17e message:what is the meaning of life?
>   user_id:00ff679f-9421-4b8b-ae7f-d11cf2adaee2] old_val:]

However, I would like the response to be mapped to struct ChatMessage.

Update:

I've tried:

```
var message ChatMessage
```

However, it doesn't seem like any of my data gets set in the struct.

> {    0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC}

My struct:

```
type ChatMessage struct {
    ID      string        `json:"id" gorethink:"id,omitempty"`
    UserID      string    `json:"user_id" gorethink:"user_id"`
    ClubID      string    `json:"club_id" gorethink:"club_id"`
    Message     string    `json:"message" gorethink:"message"`
    Date    time.Time     `json:"date" gorethink:"date"`
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

The problem was that I didn't specify a field on the rethinkdb change request.

Previous code:

```
chatFeedCursor, _ := gorethink.Table("club_chat").Changes().Run(gorethinkSession)
```

Working Code:

```
chatFeedCursor, _ := gorethink.Table("club_chat").Changes().Field("new_val").Run(gorethinkSession)
```

Now the .Next() value maps to my struct with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to unmarshal the changefeed cursor value to a specific struct type, but keep both the new and the old value, you could use a library for decoding generic map values into native Go structures, like [mapstructure](https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure), to obtain a neat result:

Import mapstructure:

```
import (
   ...
    "github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure"
   ...
)
```

Now you can do something like:

```
    cursor, err := r.Table("club_chat").
        Changes().
        Run(db.Session)

    if err != nil {
        // manage error
    }

    var changeFeed map[string]interface{}
    for cursor.Next(&changeFeed) {

        var oldVal, newVal ChatMessage
        if changeFeed["old_val"] != nil {
            mapstructure.Decode(changeFeed["old_val"], &oldVal)
        }

        if changeFeed["new_val"] != nil {
            mapstructure.Decode(changeFeed["new_val"], &newVal)
        }

      // Do what you want with the values
```